# Some of the label values disappear after using check_overlap=T in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a circular bar graph using ggplot2. After adding geom_text() to add labels, my graph was looking messy, so I used check_overlap=T in the geom_text(). After adding check_overlap=T, some of the values on the labels are not shown in the graph. Is there a way to fix this?

This is my data;

```
structure(list(Corporations = c("Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", 
"Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", 
"Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", 
"Private Haushalte", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", 
"Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck"
), Instruments = c("Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", "Bargeld", 
"Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen"), Q1.19 = c(NA, 6299, 555223, 2427, 32995, 
2189603, 56996, 31362, 1198580, 139931, 38424, 4340085, 3202446, 
60692, 2975850, 89437, 588297, 342623, NA, 230878, 2251130, 12242, 
1625426, 1255442, 2281472, 0, 30619, NA, 487, 319099, 6259, 38429, 
617751, 948, 41669, 99347, NA, NA, 62271, 1840, 15811, 92797, 
NA, 422, NA), Q2.19 = c(NA, 6454, 551837, 2085, 31926, 2198338, 
57709, 32616, 1178917, 148943, 39256, 4359950, 3303698, 60708, 
3056242, 89612, 726303, 358358, NA, 239382, 2284960, 12250, 1645940, 
1292362, 2297914, 0, 31502, NA, 487, 330817, 6150, 39239, 645949, 
954, -41925, 94741, NA, NA, 62626, 1839, 15866, 95467, NA, 362, 
NA), Q3.19 = c(NA, 6466, 573901, 2295, 32219, 2232079, 58430, 
32051, 1203447, 162442, 39311, 4261998, 3420453, 60885, 3157147, 
91016, 920818, 382937, NA, 249723, 2298254, 12225, 1667098, 1322047, 
2313450, 0, 32251, NA, 487, 330779, 6004, 42480, 676359, 960, 
-47370, 108842, NA, NA, 62854, 1913, 16052, 98454, NA, 480, NA
), Q4.19 = c(NA, 7386, 590593, 2183, 33011, 2317831, 59160, 31542, 
1229358, 161204, 44712, 4089901, 3332533, 60485, 3266643, 91257, 
761489, 440720, NA, 260243, 2337146, 12045, 1686127, 1383188, 
2331436, 0, 32043, NA, 487, 313552, 5315, 40097, 670891, 966, 
-42715, 104839, NA, NA, 61959, 1919, 16446, 103620, NA, 380, 
NA), Q1.20 = c(NA, 6742, 588896, 1979, 33086, 2103282, 59900, 
44907, 1178927, 173489, 49423, 4494126, 3354457, 61080, 2975370, 
90025, 1102066, 400057, NA, 279788, 2341738, 10748, 1703401, 
1220313, 2354882, 0, 31439, NA, 487, 350979, 5709, 41296, 664676, 
972, -44212, 115474, NA, NA, 62339, 1740, 16510, 94113, NA, 412, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

This is my code;

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Corporations, y = Q1.19, fill = Instruments)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar() +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(underline("Quartal 1, 2019")))) +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color="red", size=2),
        legend.box.margin = margin(16, 6, 6, 6),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=Q1.19, label = paste(Q1.19)), 
            size = 4, position = position_fill(vjust = 0.7))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the intended result of `check_overlap = T`: to remove any labels that overlap other labels. I would suggest you try `ggrepel::geom_text_repel()`, which bounces the labels far enough away from the points that they shouldn't overlap. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html) for more information.